# Double free or corruption when keeping std::vector<std::weak_ptr>> in std::map

Tags: c++, stl

Short: a (network) `Client` has a `std::shared_ptr<Session>`, when a client is destroyed, from `~Client` the function `queueSessionRemoval(const std::shared_ptr<Session> &session)` is called, which adds it to `std::map<std::chrono::seconds, std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Session>>> queuedSessionRemovals`. This crashes with "double free or corruption".

Simplified code:

```
class Store
{
    std::map<std::chrono::seconds, std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Session>>> queuedSessionRemovals;
    std::mutex queuedSessionRemovalsMutex;
}

Client::~Client()
{
    // removed irrelevant stuff.

    // session is std::shared_ptr<Session>
    store->queueSessionRemoval(session);
}

void Store::expireSessions()
{
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(this->queuedSessionRemovalsMutex);

        // Iterate over queuedSessionRemovals, etc, etc
        // Removed; not important

}

void Store::queueSessionRemoval(const std::shared_ptr<Session> &session)
{
    if (!session)
        return;

    auto removeAt = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(session->getSessionExpiryInterval());
    std::chrono::seconds secondsSinceEpoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(removeAt.time_since_epoch());
    
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(this->queuedSessionRemovalsMutex);
    queuedSessionRemovals[secondsSinceEpoch].push_back(session);
}
```

The line that crashes is `queuedSessionRemovals[secondsSinceEpoch].push_back(session);`

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007fc09ab93859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007fc09abfe29e in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7fc09ad28298 "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#3  0x00007fc09ac0632c in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7fc09ad2a628 "double free or corruption (fasttop)") at malloc.c:5347
#4  0x00007fc09ac07c95 in _int_free (av=0x7fc084000020, p=0x7fc0842197b0, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4266
#5  0x00005590242cfb82 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::weak_ptr<Session> >::deallocate (this=0x7fc08021eaf8, __p=0x7fc0842197c0) at /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:128
#6  0x00005590242cfae2 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::weak_ptr<Session> > >::deallocate (__a=..., __p=0x7fc0842197c0, __n=4115453) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:469
#7  0x00005590242cfa3a in std::_Vector_base<std::weak_ptr<Session>, std::allocator<std::weak_ptr<Session> > >::_M_deallocate (this=0x7fc08021eaf8, __p=0x7fc0842197c0, __n=4115453) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:351
#8  0x000055902430fe13 in std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Session>, std::allocator<std::weak_ptr<Session> > >::_M_realloc_insert<std::weak_ptr<Session> > (this=0x7fc08021eaf8, 
    __position=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x119>) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:500
#9  0x000055902430c384 in std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Session>, std::allocator<std::weak_ptr<Session> > >::emplace_back<std::weak_ptr<Session> > (this=0x7fc08021eaf8) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:121
#10 0x00005590243091da in std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Session>, std::allocator<std::weak_ptr<Session> > >::push_back (this=0x7fc08021eaf8, __x=...) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1201
#11 0x0000559024304a3a in Store::queueSessionRemoval (this=0x559024648200, session=std::shared_ptr<class Session> (use count 2, weak count 2) = {...}) at /bla/store.cpp:726
#12 0x00005590242e41f7 in Client::~Client (this=0x55902482ca00, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /bla/client.cpp:91
```

There is nothing going on like putting a raw pointer in a shared or weak one. It's all properly managed and the session is created with `std::make_shared`.

So, `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::weak_ptr<Session> >::deallocate` crashes. Probably related to re-balancing of the map.

Changing the `std::weak_ptr` to a `std::shared_ptr` in `queuedSessionRemovals` doesn't help. Using other containers doesn't help. Making the argument to `queueSessionRemoval` not a reference doesn't help.

When I use a `std::list` instead of a `std::map` and keep it sorted with `std::upper_bound` to find the position, very funky results happen, where an empty list has a `size() > 0`.

The only thing I can imagine is that it has something to do with calling this from a destructor, but at that point in time, the `client::session`  is still a valid shared pointer, so I wouldn't know why.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(this->queuedSessionRemovalsMutex);` cannot make sense there. The destructor has already been entered, so every attempt of another thread to access this mutex and the guarded member cannot possibly be safe.

Comment: ```queuedSessionRemovals``` looks like it is a global, yet each Client has its own ```queuedSessionRemovalsMutex```. Does that mean you have multiple mutexes protecting the same variable? That's not going to work. Or is ```queuedSessionRemovalsMutex``` a reference member?

Comment: And on top of all that: A lock guard instantiated like `lock_guard<...>(mtx);` is a temporary object. It locks the `mtx` and and unlocks it right away. Certainly not what you intended.

Comment: I was overzealous in simplifying the code (what generated the questions/confusion), so I clarified a bit, but I can't (yet) provide a minimal reproducible example, because of the illusive nature. I'll try to work on it though.

Comment: @j6t the code was not clear so I'll accept the comments, but the temp object was it. I cannot believe I spent so much time overlooking that. There are about 40 places where I construct lock guards, and this one was wrong.

Comment: Heh! A trick: only change the `;` to `,`, and you get a temporary object that outlives the function call on the next line. This way you do not have to invent an otherwise unused name. (But it needs a comment, or others will scratch their heads over it...)